# QSqlQuery Postgres multiple select

Tags: postgresql, qt

I have a query which contains two part. First part call function which creates a temporary table, second part select data from this table.

```
SELECT create_data_slice(15962, NULL, ARRAY[[15726]]);

SELECT
    AK."15962_15726" as AK_NAME
FROM
    t15962 AK
GROUP BY
    AK."15962_15726;"
```

If I execute this query in PgAdmin, it turns right result with data. But if I execute it in Qt:

```
QSqlDatabase db = store->get_db();
QSqlQuery query(db);
query.exec(sql);
```

it executes only the first part (create temporary table), but do not execute second part and do not return data.

Comment: I try this multiple select in qt and PgAdmin:
    `SELECT 1;
    SELECT 2;`
PgAdmin returns value "2" but Qt `query.exec(sql)` returns one row with value "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a transaction like this:

```
QSqlDatabase::database().transaction();
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("SELECT create_data_slice(15962, NULL, ARRAY[[15726]]);");
if (query.next()) 
{
    int employeeId = query.value(0).toInt();
    query.exec("SELECT AK."15962_15726" as AK_NAME FROM t15962 AK GROUP BY AK."15962_15726;");
    while(query.next())
    {
         qDebug() << query.value().toString(); ///or what you want to do with data
    }
}
QSqlDatabase::database().commit();
```